# MVC 4.0 - sign in using Google

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, membership-provider

I know there's a lot of information about this subject, but I just can't seem to find an answer suitable to my specific needs:
I opened a new MVC 4.0 **basic** application (meaning, no "AuthConfig.cs" file exist).
I have already successfully implemented Facebook sign-in. 
I can't seem to find any way to do the same with Google.

I already have a custom "Connect with google" button. I need a very simple code to authenticate using google. Please bare in mind, that after authentication, I need to get user information, and also get a hold of the user's calendar.

Please help

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some Code to help you get started

In AuthConfig file

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new Mvc.GoogleCustomClient(), "Google", null);
```

In GoogleCustomClient.cs

```
public class GoogleCustomClient : OpenIdClient
{


    public GoogleCustomClient()
        : base("google", WellKnownProviders.Google) { }



    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the extra data obtained from the response message when authentication is successful.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="response">
    /// The response message. 
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>A dictionary of profile data; or null if no data is available.</returns>
    protected override Dictionary<string, string> GetExtraData(IAuthenticationResponse response)
    {
        FetchResponse fetchResponse = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();
        if (fetchResponse != null)
        {
            var extraData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            extraData.Add("email", fetchResponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email));
            extraData.Add("country", fetchResponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.HomeAddress.Country));
            extraData.Add("firstName", fetchResponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First));
            extraData.Add("lastName", fetchResponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last));

            return extraData;
        }

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called just before the authentication request is sent to service provider.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">
    /// The request. 
    /// </param>
    protected override void OnBeforeSendingAuthenticationRequest(IAuthenticationRequest request)
    {
        // Attribute Exchange extensions
        var fetchRequest = new FetchRequest();
        fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
        fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.HomeAddress.Country);
        fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First);
        fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last);

        request.AddExtension(fetchRequest);
    }


}
```

You can Use this Code to retrieve the User Information from google.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the replay Kumer, but as I mentioned, it's a basic MVC application, and I don't have AuthConfig..